# can't read data from a few specific tables with db_datareader role

Tags: azure-sql-database

I do have admin permission for a certain Azure SQL Server. So using my admin login I created a database user against a specific Azure SQL database in the following manner:-

```
CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD = '<pwd>'

ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [myuser]
```

After this I successfully logged into the database using this new credential for `myuser`. I discovered that while I can query data from most of the tables , there are certain tables for which I can't select any data. I can see the table name in SSMS , also no error for SELECT queries against those tables I receive , the only issue is that SELECT doesn't return any data ( 0 rows ) for those tables. If I fire SELECT using my admin credentials , I can very much see the result.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the same issue using the same commands which you have shared.

FYI, as a part of repro, I created an Azure SQL Server and then SQL database in the same server. I added three sample tables to match the scenario as you mentioned. Then I created user and grant db_datareader role with the same commands as you mentioned. It worked fine for me. I’m able to read the data of all the table in that specific database.

I suggest you consider [How to Create Login, User & Assign Permissions in SQL Server](https://www.guru99.com/sql-server-create-user.html) and [Overview of db_datareader role](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-the-db_datareader-role/).

Alternatively, you can **grant select permission to those tables which you are unable to read using below command**:

`GRANT SELECT ON <tablename> TO <user>;`

Comment: I tried everything , nothing helped. In fact I even granted db_owner role to it , and with that also still the same , for certain tables no data was returned under that login. There is no error also , it's just that 0 rows are returned. I also tried to explicitly grant permissions to those tables like you suggested , still the same.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new login within that database and add user to it, then give permission to this new user?